# Haskell no data constructors for type synonym

Tags: haskell, types

I've defined a haskell data type with constructors and a type synonym for it.I'm not able to use its data constructors.

Type definition :

```
module BinaryTreeModule(BinaryTree,..) where
data BinaryTree a = Empty | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
```

type synonym:

```
import BinaryTreeModule(BinaryTree)
type BST = BinaryTree
```

usage:

```
insert :: a -> BST a -> BST a
insert _ Empty = ...
insert _ Node .. = ...
```

I'm getting an error saying Empty and Node constructors not found.

I've also defined them in different files. If BST is just a synonym for BinaryTree shouldn't their constructors be the same ?

Also is there a better way to "inherit" the BinaryTree type to different types? Are typeclasses the correct solution here?

Edit: added how I'm importing between files

Comment: Are you exposing both the `Empty` and `Node` constructors from your BinaryTree module?

Comment: and on top are you importing them as well `import MyModule(BinaryTree)` vs. `import MyModule(BinaryTree(..))` - also note that `import MyModule(BST)` is the same as the first!

Comment: Okay, I'm importing like `import MyModule(BinaryTree)`. How do i import the data constructors i.e. BinaryTree(..)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Type synonyms are of only fairly limited utility in Haskell. There are some special situations in `lens` and `pipes` and probably elsewhere where they're valuable, but in typical circumstances, you probably just shouldn't use them. GHC's type families are much more often useful, but they're a more advanced feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After @Carsten's comment, I realised I'm not importing the constructors from the module

`import BinaryTreeModule(BinaryTree(Empty,Node))`
 fixed the issue